# Open links Explicitly in Safari from a Table Detail View

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiwebview, safari, uiwebviewdelegate

All,

I have rich text, with links, in my UITableView's detail View:

[image]

When a link is pressed, the URL is loaded into the UIWebView where the rich text is being displayed. I'd like the URLs to open in Safari instead.

Can someone tell me how to accomplish this correctly? Is there a UIWebView delegate method suited for this purpose?

Thanks

Comment: possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/q/5899990/1487063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// where url is an NSURL

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

This will open the link in the default OS browser.

Documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW14).